# Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets. Prove that $A\cup C\subseteq B\cup C$ iff $A\setminus C\subseteq B\setminus C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Not a duplicate of

[Prove that $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$ iff $A \setminus C \subseteq B \setminus C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3643654/prove-that-a-cup-c-subseteq-b-cup-c-iff-a-setminus-c-subseteq-b-setminu)

[Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets. Prove that $A ∪ C ⊆ B ∪ C$ iff $A \setminus C ⊆ B \setminus C$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399611/suppose-a-b-and-c-are-sets-prove-that-a-%e2%88%aa-c-%e2%8a%86-b-%e2%88%aa-c-iff-a-setminus)

This is exercise $3.5.6$ from the book *How to Prove it* by Velleman $($$2^{nd}$ edition$)$:

Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets. Prove that $A\cup C\subseteq B\cup C$ iff $A\setminus C\subseteq B\setminus C$.

Here is my proof:

$(\rightarrow)$ Suppose $A\cup C\subseteq B\cup C$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A\setminus C$. This means $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$. Since $x\in A$, $x\in A\cup C$. From $A\cup C\subseteq B\cup C$ and $x\in A\cup C$, $x\in B\cup C$. Now we consider two different cases.

Case $1.$ Suppose $x\in B$. Since $x\notin C$, $x\in B\setminus C$.

Case $2.$ Suppose $x\in C$ which produces a contradiction.

From $x\in B\setminus C$ or a contradiction we obtain $x\in B\setminus C$. Thus if $x\in A\setminus C$ then $x\in B\setminus C$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $\forall x(x\in A\setminus C\rightarrow x\in B\setminus C)$ and so $A\setminus C\subseteq B\setminus C$. Therefore if $A\cup C\subseteq B\cup C$ then $A\setminus C\subseteq B\setminus C$.

$(\leftarrow)$ Suppose $A\setminus C\subseteq B\setminus C$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A\cup C$. This means $x\in A$ or $x\in C$. Now we consider two different cases.

Case $1.$ Suppose $x\in C$. Ergo $x\in B\cup C$.

Case $2.$ Suppose $x\notin C$. From $x\in A\cup C$ and $x\notin C$, $x\in A$. Ergo $x\in A\setminus C$. Since $A\setminus C\subseteq B\setminus C$, $x\in B\setminus C$ which means $x\in B$. Thus $x\in B\cup C$.

Since the above cases are exhaustive, $x\in B\cup C$. Thus if $x\in A\cup C$ then $x\in B\cup C$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $\forall x(x\in A\cup C\rightarrow x\in B\cup C)$ and so $A\cup C\subseteq B\cup C$. Therefore if $A\setminus C\subseteq B\setminus C$ then $A\cup C\subseteq B\cup C$.

Ergo $A\cup C\subseteq B\cup C$ iff $A\setminus C\subseteq B\setminus C$. $Q.E.D.$

Is my proof valid$?$

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Yes, it is the standard proof. It seems to be correct to me

Comment: Doesn't it follow from the fact that $A \cup C = (A\backslash C) \cup C$?

Comment: @QuangHoang Could you please explain more?

Comment: $A\cup C \subset B\cup C \iff (A \backslash C) \cup C \subset (B\backslash C) \cup C$. Since $A \backslash C \cap C = \emptyset$ and $B \backslash C \cap C = \emptyset$, the latter is equivalent to $A\backslash C \subset B \backslash C$.

Comment: @QuangHoang How do you see these connections? When you write it down for me it makes sense to me but I cannot see it on my own. Is it because I'm a newbie and didn't study set theory extensively yet or my method of studying could be wrong?

Comment: Don't worry, it comes with practices. Also, for this type of exercise, [Venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) is very helpful.